# PHP MYSQL Join two tables and echo Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

Table `personal_info` has the information

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   id   | fname  | lname  | email  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Table `other_info` has the information

```
+--------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+
|   id   | university_name | course_name  | business_name  |
+--------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+
|        |                 |              |                |
+--------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Now i want to use PHP to join the tables and get information from the two tables i decided to do something like this

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect : '.mysqli_error());
$sql = "select * from personal_info, other_info "; // Here i want to join the two tables to echo results
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){

    echo "$row['fname'] ."".$row['lname'] ."".$row['university_name'] ."".$row['course_name'] ."".$row['businessname'] ";
}


?>
```

How do i join the tables and get data?

Comment: Could you please share bit more information. Provide the queries which you're searching and show some example data which would be in the database.

Comment: if database have same fields you mentioned then not possible to JOIN tables as there is no matching field (reference)

Comment: what is the relation or common column between `personal_info` and `other_info fields` if its id column then this is the query `SELECT pinfo.*,oinfo.* from personal_info pinfo,other_info oinfo where pinfo.id = oinfo.id group by pinfo.id;`

Comment: means i can make a column like say username and select them both together using username ? @ArunpandianM

Comment: yes if username in the personal info is  same for other_info

Comment: _Side note:_ . You can remove all quotes from your echo and just have: `echo $row['fname'] . $row['lname'] ...etc`. It will produce the same result.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set a foreign key in the other_info table first, so you can join over this key.

then a select like this should work

```
select fname, lname, university_name, course_name, business_name
from personal_info t1
inner join other_info t2 on (t1.id = t2.personal_id)
```

**t2.personal_id** is the foreign key column in the table other_info

Comment: I think it's more likely that it's a one to many relationship the other way around. Multiple people can have the same university. Your example makes it that a university only can have one person. The best solution would probably be to have a junction table, though.

Comment: true.
a junction table would look like this:
junction_table: personal_id, university_id

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between `personal_info` and `other_info` table. Through which, it is impossible to know the other information related to particular record.

So, you can do one thing. Make one column `personal_info_id` in `other_info` table, which will have store the `id` of `personal_info` table.

Like:

**personal_info**

```
id | fname | lname | email
1   UserFN  UserLN  user@email
2   User2FN User2LN user2@email
```

**other_info**

```
id | personal_info_id | university_name | course_name | business_name
1       1                 UniV               PHP           ABC
2       2                 UniVY              C++           XYZ
```

Now, you can join 2 tables by using `personal_info_id` of `other_info` with `id` of `personal_info`

```
SELECT pfo.*, ofo.* 
FROM personal_info pfo, other_info ofo 
WHERE pfo.id = ofo.personal_info_id;
```

***Updated Code***

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect : '.mysqli_error());
$sql = "SELECT pfo.*, ofo.* FROM personal_info pfo, other_info ofo WHERE pfo.id = ofo.personal_info_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){
  echo $row['fname']." / ".$row['lname']." / ".$row['email']." / ".$row['university_name']." / ".$row['course_name']." / ".$row['business_name'];
}?>
```

Comment: means i can also make a column for say username for instance on both tables and then make a join like this https://pastebin.com/ibwj46Rv

Comment: I saw this. But, this is not the good approach. If name got changed in personal_info table. Then, you will not be able to fetch the correct details. Storing the id in other table will give you correct data in spite of updating any records in personal_info table @JamesIbrahimov

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect : '.mysqli_error());
$sql = "SELECT personal_info.id,personal_info.fname,personal_info.lname,personal_info.email, other_info.university_name,other_info.course_name,other_info.business_name FROM personal_info FULL OUTER JOIN other_info ON personal_info.id=other_info.id;"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){

    echo "$row['fname'] ."".$row['lname'] ."".$row['university_name'] ."".$row['course_name'] ."".$row['businessname'] ";
}


?>
```